# openlayers 3: how to draw sth using canvas.getContext('2d') on top of the map

Tags: html, canvas, openlayers-3

I want to draw some geometry in the map using canvas.getContext('2d'). However, the geometry I've drawn just show for a while. It disappear when I pan/zoom the map. How can I draw a permanent geometry through this way?

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.19.1/ol.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.19.1/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function init()
        {
            var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
                            title:'basemap',
                 source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                   layer: 'toner'
                 })
               });

            map = new ol.Map( {layers:[raster],target:'map',  view: new ol.View({
      center: [113,25],
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      zoom: 6
    })} );

        };


        function drawSth(){
            var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            // begin custom shape
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.moveTo(170, 80);
                  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
                  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
                  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
                  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
                  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
                  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

                  // complete custom shape
                  context.closePath();
                  context.lineWidth = 5;
                  context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
                  context.fill();
                  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
                  context.stroke();
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="controls">         
        <button onclick="drawSth();">just draw sth</button></br></br>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It turns out to be such a difficult thing to anchor the graphic to map. I have written a function "canvasOverlay", which would listen on pointerdrag and moveend event of the map. Although it worked out, the effect was not so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with an ol.source.ImageCanvas and its canvasFunction.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/45oxL7rf/

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      title: 'basemap',
      source: new ol.source.Stamen({ layer: 'toner' })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageCanvas({
        canvasFunction: function (extent, resolution, pixelRatio, size, projection) {
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = size[0];
          canvas.height = size[1];

          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          // begin custom shape
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(170, 80);
          context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
          context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
          context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
          context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
          context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
          context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

          // complete custom shape
          context.closePath();
          context.lineWidth = 5;
          context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
          context.fill();
          context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
          context.stroke();

          return canvas;
        },
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-97, 38]),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

Note that I just copy/pasted your canvas drawing and left it as is. As you pan the map, your graphic will not be anchored to the map as you might expect, since you're drawing to static pixel coordinates. In your real app, you'll likely be calculating the proper pixel coordinates based on the arguments passed into your canvasFunction.

Comment: Jeff, thanks very much for the canvasFunction clue. I could handle the rest with openlayers example.

Comment: Glad that helped you! If you consider this a good answer, could you please mark it as "Answered"?  thank you, and best of luck!

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I'm busy with another project recently. Of course your reply answered my question.  Thank you and enjoy!