# Openlayers: Why do my drawings on my image canvas layer move on zoom?

Tags: javascript, canvas, openlayers-3, geo

I have an OSM Layer, a static ImageLayer and a CanvasImageLayer on top. I want to draw at specific pixel positions (relative to the 0,0 origin of the canvas) icons, e.g. at position 10,10.

This works, however, I do not understand why my canvas is resized when I move and why my Icons are then at the wrong position?
Even if I calculate the positions based on the new canvas size, they move and don't stay in their position. I really would need an explanation to understand this.

I oriented myself on this [ImageCanvas example](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter03_04_imagecanvas.html).

I only found this related question, but it does not explain it, nor does it give a solution to the problem:
[openlayers 3: how to draw sth using canvas.getContext('2d') on top of the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839554/openlayers-3-how-to-draw-sth-using-canvas-getcontext2d-on-top-of-the-map)